# MongoDB crashes with signal 6

Tags: mongodb

```
    Tue Apr  1 17:21:38.898 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58349 #42 (5 connections now open)
Tue Apr  1 17:21:50.855 [journal] exception in dur::groupCommitLL causing immediate shutdown: boost::filesystem::current_path: Too many open files in system
Tue Apr  1 17:21:50.855 dur4
Tue Apr  1 17:21:50.855 Got signal: 6 (Abort trap: 6).

Tue Apr  1 17:21:50.858 Backtrace:
0x100447d8b 0x100001531 0x7fff9225990a 0x104e80818 0x7fff922b0f61 0x1001e462a 0x10016dc3c 0x10016d537 0x10047a8b5 0x7fff9226b772 0x7fff922581a1 
 0   mongod                              0x0000000100447d8b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongod                              0x0000000100001531 _ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi + 225
 2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff9225990a _sigtramp + 26
 3   ???                                 0x0000000104e80818 0x0 + 4377282584
 4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff922b0f61 abort + 143
 5   mongod                              0x00000001001e462a _ZN5mongo10mongoAbortEPKc + 90
 6   mongod                              0x000000010016dc3c _ZN5mongo3dur27groupCommitWithLimitedLocksEv + 1052
 7   mongod                              0x000000010016d537 _ZN5mongo3dur9durThreadEv + 583
 8   mongod                              0x000000010047a8b5 thread_proxy + 229
 9   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff9226b772 _pthread_start + 327
 10  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff922581a1 thread_start + 13
```

Would anyone know what is causing mongo to crash? If you need more context please comment - I'll see what else I can dig up.

Comment: Are you running this in linux?

Comment: Yes - on mac os - mountain lion - installed using homebrew

Comment: Check if ulimit is the culprit. I have seen such errors in Linux where ulimit is the culprit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the ulimit value works for me (previously it was 256):

```
ulimit -n 1000
```

In this case I'm setting ulimit to 1.000, but you can use whatever value that you want.

According to documentation:

> ulimit refers to the per-user limitations for various resources.
>   Therefore, if your mongod instance executes as a user that is also
>   running multiple processes, or multiple mongod processes, you might
>   see contention for these resources. Also, be aware that the processes
>   value (i.e. -u) refers to the combined number of distinct processes
>   and sub-process threads.